# Generating element sizes based on ratios

Tags: php, html, css, parsing

This may be a weird type of question, but how would you generate square links which have their size based on how many links the next page contains.

The amount of links would be generate using this:

```
$directory = "directory/subdirectory1/";
$files = glob($directory . "*");
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(is_dir($file))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

So lets say that in the folder directory we had 6 sub-directories names subdirectory1 - 6, for each directory we would find out how many directories each one has and then store this in an array.

From this we can start generating the squares. Everything should be done based on percentages, so we don't need to worry about absolutes. They shouldn't have like tiny sizes.

So lets say `subdirectory1` had 18 directories in it, `subdirectory2` had 15, `subdirectory3` had 12, `subdirectory4` had 9, `subdirectory5` had 6, and `subdirectory6` had 2

In this situation its obvious that `subdirectory1` should be the biggest, so that should be 50% of the page, then `subdirectory2`, `subdirectory3` and `subdirectory4` have very similar amounts, so I would say split them across the other 50% by having half the height of `subdirectory1` and putting `subdirectory4` on the next line, then the last 2 would be 25% each of that line, resulting in something like this:

[image]

But how could I cater for any ratios of directories, any algorithms that could help me out? This needs to be able to accommodate 30+ different sub-directories.

Thanks for your time :)

---

**Update**

So I have decided to group them on more then just the amount of folders, what I will do is store them in a database, and group them by parent ID.

I will base the sizes on a few different things, first being parent ID, which will be the bulk of the determination, then popularity, so analytic data, how much has the page been viewed, how much have people interacted with the post (comments, votes, etc).

From this data I will give each parent a score between 0 and 100 and base the size upon that, there will be 4 sizes and they will be assigned pretty easily, x > 75 biggest, 50 < x > 75 largish, 25 > x < 50 normal, 0 > x < 25 small, 0 none.

Anyone have any suggestions for the algorithm I should use for the scores?

Comment: From your example, the ratio should be 29%, 24%, 19%, 15%, 10%, 3% (rounded, of course). So you'll have to be more specific about how to determine the "output" percentage.

Comment: If you look I showed that I don't want absolutes like this, I want to be able to group different sub-directories into the same range, but how to do this is the problem. I know how to do math and work out percentages... if that was the problem I would have asked on math.

Comment: Then you'll have to define what "range" you want to use. Your example groups `2, 3, 4` into one and `5, 6` into another one, but `5` is much close to `4` than to `6`, and `2`-`3`=`4`-`5`=5%, so you're actually not grouping by "similar amounts" but by "number range". So you'll have to determine your desired range, e.g. `30+, 20-30, 10-20, 10-` and assign desired size to them, e.g. `50%, 25%, 12%, 6%`.

Comment: I can see your logic behind that, when making the example I wasn't really thinking to much about the numbers sorry. I think giving them scores is the best way to go, also adding analytic data into those scores as well, then out of that range base base their sizes according to what quartile they are in.